Inconsistency with Lagrange Multiplier Method
I recently read a question here and attempted to solve it with the method of Lagrange Multiplier:

If $x$ and $y$ are real number such that $x^2+2xy-y^2=6$, then find the minimum value of $(x^2+y^2)^2$

If we take the Lagrange Multiplier to be $l$, the Lagrangian function becomes: $$F(x,y,l)=(x^2+y^2)^2+l(x^2+2xy-y^2-6)$$
$$\implies F(x,y,l)=x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2+l(x^2+2xy-y^2-6)$$
Differentiating it partially with respect to x, y, and l and setting each equal to 0:
$$F_x=4x^3+4xy^2+2xl+2yl=0$$
$$F_y=4y^3+4yx^2+2xl-2yl=0$$
$$F_l=x^2+2xy-y^2-6=0$$
On solving the three simultaneous equations in $x, y, \text{and } l$, Wolfram|Alpha gives the following solutions:


While it is clear that the minimum value is 18 and not among the ones in the screenshot by other methods like inequality manipulation, using polar coordinates, etc. while I was still unable to determine the cause of this inconsistency.
NOTE: The above method gives the same answer if I perform the above method for $2(x^2+y^2)^2$ instead of $(x^2+y^2)^2$.
Here are the screenshots for your reference:


EDIT: Notice that the last lines in the outputs of Wolfram|Alpha in the screenshots state $(x^2+y^2)^2=±±0$, any explanation for this? It's only possible when $x=y=0$, but this does not satisfy the constraint. Also, what is the significance of $±±$?

Could you provide (through WA or not) numerical approximations of these exact values, in order I can verify the explanation I am thinking to ?

It simplifies to $18$. In Sage,
a = sqrt(2) - 1
expr = 27/4 - 9/sqrt(2) + 3/4 * a * (sqrt(6) * a^(3/2) + 2 sqrt(6 * a))^2 + 1/16 * (sqrt(6) * a^(3/2) + 2 sqrt(6 * a))^4
expr.simplify_full()

gives
$$
-6 \, \sqrt{6} {\left(11 \, \sqrt{2} - 16\right)} \sqrt{6 \, \sqrt{2} - 6} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} - 1} - 972 \, \sqrt{2} + 1386.
$$
You then have to manually combine the square roots in the middle but it will simplify to $18$.

You can often get a messy result if you just ask the computer to solve the entire problem at once rather than going step by step and looking for places where you can simplify.
For instance: we can simplify $(x^2 + y^2)^2$ to $x^2 + y^2$ since these will be minimized at the same point. Then we plug those equations into the computer (this time in Singular):
ring R = 0,(x,y,l),lp;
ideal I = x2 + 2xy - y2 - 6, 2x + 2y - 2xl, 2x - 2y - 2yl;
eliminate(I, yl);

To get
$$\begin{equation} \tag{1}\label{eq:4x412x29}
4x^4-12x^2-9
\end{equation}$$
And so $x^2 = \frac32 \sqrt2 + \frac32$. Similarly $y^2 = \frac32 \sqrt2 - \frac32$ (use eliminate(I, xl)). So we find that
$$x^2 + y^2 = 3 \sqrt 2.$$
If you don't have Sage and/or Singular, you can use this online cell to compute in either language.
See another place that I'm simplifying the problem that the computer won't is that I can recognize \eqref{eq:4x412x29} as a quadratic in $x^2$ but the computer might try to use the quartic formula to solve it.

It is interesting to note the method of problem solving of calculators. They just won't provide the simplified expressions at all.

Now given that (x²+y²)² will be minimised when (x²+y²) is minimised, it is easier to solve on paper.

One last doubt, notice that the last line in the outputs of WA in my question states $(x²+y²)²=±±0$, any explanation for this? It's only possible when x=y=0, but this does not satisfy the constraint. Also, what is the significance of ±±?

@Yatharth I'm not really sure where that comes from. Sometimes with Lagrange multipliers you get extraneous solutions where $\lambda = 0$ but they should at least satisfy the constraint. I also haven't seen a double $\pm$ before.
